# Mongoose Error with trying to use findOneAndUpdate and update an array of objects

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to update an Array of Objects called `watched_movies_list` in my UserSchema using Mongoose. By utilizing the `$push` object given the user id by passing `_id: req.body.id`. However I'm getting this casting error(below) when trying to update the `watched_movies_list` field.

```
reason: CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "{
    title: 'Luck',
    overview: 'Suddenly finding herself in the never-before-seen Land of Luck, the unluckiest person in the world must unite with the magical creatures there to turn her luck around.',
    poster_path: '/1HOYvwGFioUFL58UVvDRG6beEDm.jpg',
    original_title: 'Luck',
    original_language: 'en',
    id: 550,
    release_date: '2022-08-05',
    genre_ids: undefined
  }" (type Object) at path "movie_meta_data" because of "BSONTypeError"
```

This is my UserSchema:

```
  watched_movies_list: [{
    movie_meta_data: {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "MovieDataSchema"
    },
    rating: {type: Number}
  }]
```

And this is the POST route:

```
  try {
    const user = await User.findOneAndUpdate(
      {_id: req.body.id},
      { "$push": { watched_movies_list: watchedMovie }});
    res.status(200).json({
      success: 'true',
      user: user
    })
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(400).json(err);
    throw err;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to push an "object" to your `watched_movies_list` array. Unfortunately this array is defined as an array of ObjectIds. You either have to first store the object in `MovieDataSchema` collection and then push only the _id to your array or define `watched_movies_list` as an array of MovieDataSchema objects (so as nested documents).

**Update after feedback from comment:**

In order to have nested documents you should define your schema as following:

```
watched_movies_list: [{
  movie: MovieDataSchema,
  rating: {type: Number}
}]
```

After that you should be able to make the following function call:

```
const user = await User.findOneAndUpdate(
      {_id: req.body.id},
      { "$push": { watched_movies_list: { movie: watchedMovie } }
);
```

or if you want to include your rating you should include it like this:

```
const user = await User.findOneAndUpdate(
      {_id: req.body.id},
      { "$push": { watched_movies_list: { movie: watchedMovie, rating: 5 } }
);
```

Comment: Okay I think I understand. However, what is the proper way to do nested documents?  Currently I have the important at the top of my User file as `const MovieDataSchema = require('./Movie').schema;` and in my `watched_movies_list` object `[MovieDataSchema] but that doesn't seem to be working either.

Comment: adjusted my answer to match your required schema.

Comment: Ah that makes so much sense. Thanks!